# inverse trigonometry

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse

1. Could anyone explain whether arc tan(sin x) can be simplified to an algebraic expression ?
2. How can we draw graph of Arc tan(sin x).
   I have done an exhaustive google search only to find nothing. Also no book on inverse trig. mentions this function.

Comment: We need to take care of periods i think

Comment: It's odd, it's $2\pi$-periodic, and it has an axis of symmetry at $x = \pi/2$. So you only need to graph it on $[0,\pi/2]$. On that interval, it's increasing. If you know calculus, you may be able to go further.

Comment: If you want to look at plots of thing in general use [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You may see the graph of the function. The blue is just arctan(x) and the red is arctan(sin(x)).

With regard to algebraic representation, I am not clear about your meaning but you could use extension into polynomials, first of the arctan(x) and than insert the sin(x) extension into it. this may be extended to any power of x, based on how accurate you want to get the algebraic (if that what your mean) description.

[image]